# List<long> to comma delimited string in C#

Tags: c#, string, list

This often comes up. I have a List and I want to go to a comma delimited string of all the elements in the list that I can use in SQL.

What is the most elegant way to do this in C#? Iterating over all of them is fine, except either the first or last element has to be special-cased since I don't want leading or trailing commas.

Got a good one-liner?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

string.Join is your friend...

```
var list = new List<long> {1, 2, 3, 4};
var commaSeparated = string.Join(",", list);
```

Comment: I believe that gives a syntax error - String.Join won't take a List<long> as a 2nd arg.

Comment: @John Shedletsky: The .NET Framework 4.0 introduced [String.Join<T> Method (String, IEnumerable<T>)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992421.aspx)

Comment: @dtb: seems to be a new method of .NET 4

Comment: @John - It compiled and gave me the expected result. As etb mentioned, there is an overload that takes an IEnumerable<T>. (It was introduced in .NET 4.)

Comment: Yeah, this is what I wish it was. Stuck with 3.5 for now. Sigh.

Comment: @John - With .NET 3.5, the best you can do is Matthew's suggestion above with the Select() and ToArray().

Comment: ASIDE: Funny how we developers now complain about being "stuck on .NET 3.5". It was pretty rocking not too long ago...

Answer (score 14):

```
List<long> items = // init here
string result = string.Join(", ", items.Select(i => i.ToString()).ToArray());
```

Not sure if it's the most elegant way, but it is a 1 liner!

Now there is also a `string.Join` that accepts an `IEnumerable<T>`, so it gets even shorter:

```
string result = string.Join(", ", items);
```

Thanks to type inference, you don't need to specified `Join<long>`

Comment: how could we do reverse? one string "1,2,3,4" to list of longs?

Answer (score 3):

```
string.Join(",", Array.ConvertAll(list.ToArray(), item => item.ToString()));
```

(written directly into the post, so I may have got a couple of the parameters wrong, but you get the idea)

Comment: This first allocates a new array from the `List<>` because of `.ToArray()`, then allocates yet another array because of `Array.ConvertAll`. Since .NET version 4.0 (Visual Studio 2010) theres an overload that works directly, `string.Join(",", list)`.

Answer (score 2):

If you were to do it manually you shouldn't have special cases for both first and last value, instead you could just do this:

```
List<long> junk = // have some values here;
string separator = string.Empty;
string list = string.Empty;

foreach(long john in junk)
{
    list += separator + john.ToString();
    separator = ", ";
}
```

Not saying you should do this, regard this just as a comment.

Answer (score 2):

```
// Content IDs
List<long> cIds = new List<long>();
cIds.Add(1);
cIds.Add(2);
cIds.Add(1);
cIds.Add(3);
cIds.Add(3);
string ids = string.Join(",", cIds.Distinct().Select(x => x.ToString()).ToArray());
// The example return the following output:
// ids = "1,2,3"
```

returns a list of unique items comma delimited.

Answer (score 1):

```
    public static string CommaSeparate(this IEnumerable<string> values)
    {
        if (values.Count() == 0) return "[none]";
        return string.Join(", ", values.ToArray());
    }
```

This is an extension method that I use to do this in my applications.  It's based on IEnumerable but should be similar for List.

Answer (score 0):

I believe [String.Join](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.join.aspx) does that.

Answer (score 0):

```
List<long> list =new List<long>(){1,2,3,4,5,6,7};

StringBuilder str =new StringBuilder();    

foreach(var i in list)
{
str.Append(i).Append(',');
}
```

This will Append the long values in (stringBuilder) str as

Ans: str = 1,2,3,4,5,6,7

Comment: This question has already had a answer marked as accepted a while ago. It's best to only revive a question if you answer really adds something useful/helpful.